# How to get list of Tabs based on Lightning Experience App

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps

I'm fiddling out with new Lightning experience. How to get the list of app names available in `Lightning Experience App Manager`? either using SOQL or APEX or API

this is not duplicate question, what I'm looking is to find out what are the custom objects/components added to this app.

```
SELECT Id,Name,Type FROM AppMenuItem WHERE Lable = 'test' AND Type = 'TabSet'
```

below is the attached image.
[image]

Comment: @glls and all --  THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE - the question  is not well-phrased - he wants the tab list of the app, and the other question and answer are totally different, please remove your duplication mark!!!!

Answer (score 1):

An app does not contain a set of components or objects - it contains a set of tabs.

Please look at the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appmenuitem.htm)  - I took the following info from the bottom:

listing the tabs can be achieve with:

**Apex**:  `Schema.describeTabs()` - see how to get metadata with the [DescribeTabSetResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_schema_describetabsetresult.htm).

**REST API**: with the `/vXX.X/tabs/` resource

**SOAP API**: with the `describeTabs()` call

Comment: I looked at the rest api and execute the call in workbench but it does not give the list of tabs associated with app. So what I’m looking to find is, I what are the tabs associated with given app name.

Comment: I do not have experience with that rest api call, but I do have with the apex code - try it, should work

Comment: I have tried `DescribeTabSetResult Class.` but it does not show my custom app, and try this, in the lightning go to setup and search for app manager->lightning experience app manager than create app and add few tabs to it with profiles and then run the code `DescribeTabSetResult class` code. Let me know if you able to see your app name and associate tabs with it.

Comment: You are right - it looks like only classic apps are in this describe

Comment: I found a way, with metadata api and ant migration tool